# How to allow a partner to encrypt a message that I can decrypt without using a random initialization vector?

Tags: encryption, initialization-vector

My company has a requirement to allow a partner vendor to log people into our web app via some kind of single sign on. We need this to be a simple process for them, not involving the use of substantial new middleware or learning curve.

We can pre-exchange any secrets that we need, as well as a database of their users, whom we want to allow to log in on our site.

My thinking is that they could just hit an endpoint on our site like `/sso/token/{token}`, where `token` is string generated as `urlencode(encrypt(user_id))`. Then I could call `decrypt(urldecode(token))` to recover `user_id`, and just log in that user (assuming the id is valid in the dataset).

The partners are using PHP, so I want to make sure to use an encryption scheme that is PHP friendly. It turns out that PHP has [openssl_encrypt](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-encrypt.php), with example code like so:

```
$key = "secret-key";
$plaintext = "message to be encrypted";
$cipher = "aes-128-gcm";

$ivlen = openssl_cipher_iv_length($cipher);
$iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($ivlen);   <--question about this line
$ciphertext = openssl_encrypt($plaintext, $cipher, $key, $options=0, $iv, $tag);
//...
//store $cipher, $iv, and $tag for decryption later
//...
$original_plaintext = openssl_decrypt($ciphertext, $cipher, $key, $options=0, $iv, $tag);
```

I see how this could be used to generate an encrypted token, which I can then decrypt, if we share in advance the secret key and initialization vector.

The thing I don't understand is that in this example, the IV is randomized, and likewise [Wikipedia says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization_vector):

> The IV is typically required to be random or pseudorandom, but sometimes an IV only needs to be unpredictable or unique. Randomization is crucial for some encryption schemes to achieve semantic security, a property whereby repeated usage of the scheme under the same key does not allow an attacker to infer relationships between (potentially similar) segments of the encrypted message.

I get that if the IV is constant, then anyone who intercepts the message can replay it, or maybe even figure out how to spoof tokens entirely. But if the IV is randomized, then the token encryption is different every time as well, and I wouldn't be able to decrypt it.

How is one supposed to do the encryption so that it avoids replays but still allows decryption? Would they just send along the IV in plaintext, like `iv~token`, and I would parse off the vector for feeding into the decrypt function, and we rely on the secret key to provide security? Is it insecure to send the IV in the clear like that?

Comment: Learn all that is learn-able about IVs by reading [this](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/initialization-vector) tag...

Comment: Nope, the IV can be sent in the clear. BTW, the Wikipedia is wrong, generally you'd only need unpredictability (for e.g. CBC) or uniqueness. Full randomness is generally not required (the key provides the randomness, the IV the uniqueness). Note that full binary unpredictability is **very close** to a randomness requirement though.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes: thanks for the clear answer. What distinction are you making between "unpredictable" and "random"?

Comment: Personally I don't believe there is any fundamental difference. I prefer Bayesian statistics and a deterministic interpretation of Quantum Mechanics, so I don't think there's any such thing as *true* randomness, merely uncertainty about the state of the universe. In practice it just means that you don't necessarily have to seed a CSPRNG generating it from physical entropy for such uses, merely having a secret seed value is enough.

Comment: I'll also note that GCM as standardized by NIST allows totally deterministic public IV generation. EG for a 96-bit IV, 32 bits are a fixed user ID and 64-bits are a message counter. Every time a new message is to be encrypted the counter gets incremented. When 2^64 - 1 messages have been encrypted, a new key must be generated.

Comment: @JoshuaFrank For e.g. CBC mode you could also use a block-encrypted counter, even using the same key (to avoid sending the IV with the ciphertext). Of course, you'd need to sync the counter between the parties. Wikipedia itself seems to make the distinction between random and unpredictable, which means that the article puts the nail in its own coffin.